# js script(ajax) - php | multiple variable comunication

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am totally new at AJAX and my code is not doing what I want it to

```js
    $(#button).onclick(function() {
        // i want to know how to get these 2 variables from php
        // file when i click on button.
        .$.ajax({
            method: ? ? ? ? ,
            url: "action.php",
            data: { ? ? ? ? ? ? ? },
            etc...);
           .$(#p1).text(var1); $(#p2).text(var2)
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="p1"></p>
<p id="p2"></p>
<button id="button" value="show"></button>
```

PHP so far:

```
$p1="Hello";
$p2="Cao";
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding or tutorial service** You have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first part is you will need to create some kind of service to get variable, easier if you create a separate file. For single file you will need to check for the content type if its a application/json or application/js. Below is very simple two_variable.php file which will provide the required values.

```
<?php
 $arr = array('value1' => "Value One", 'value2' => "Value 2");     
 echo json_encode($arr);
```

Then your main page let's call it index.php. you can us the below function to display the values.

```
$.getJSON("two_variable.php",function( data ) {
     $("#p1").text(data.value1);
     $("#p2").text(data.value2);
 });)
```

So what will happen is $.get which an abstraction of $.ajax will request the two_variable.php which will provide JSON object and that you can access and populate your page with it.

Hope this make sense, if not let me know.

Comment: ooouu yea bro thanks a lot thanks thanks thanks i just added $.getJSON and it works thank you so much you made my day :) thanks